# Why do my controller's instance variables not work in views (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, instance-variables

I would like to add a couple of instance variables to my controller, since the variables in question are required from within more than one action's view. However, the below example does not work as I would expect.

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController
  @var1 = "Cheese"
  @var2 = "Tomato"

  def show_pizza_topping
    # What I want is the above instance vars from within the view here
  end

  def show_sandwich_filling
    # What I want is the above instance vars from within the view here
  end
end
```

As I understand it, Rails takes the instance variables from the controller and makes them available in the view. If I assign the same variables within the action methods, it works fine - but I don't want to do it twice. Why does my way not work?

*(Note: this is a bit of a rubbish example, but I hope it makes sense)*

EDIT: I have found the answer to this question here: [When do Ruby instance variables get set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826734/when-do-ruby-instance-variables-get-set)

EDIT 2: when is the best time to use filters such as before_filter and the initialize method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These types of things should be handled in a `before_filter`. A before filter, like the name implies, is a method that will get called before any actions, or only the ones you declare. An example:

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :set_toppings

  def show_pizza_topping
    # What I want is the above instance vars from within the view here
  end

  def show_sandwich_filling
    # What I want is the above instance vars from within the view here
  end

protected

  def set_toppings
    @var1 = "Cheese"
    @var2 = "Tomato"
  end

end
```

Or, you could have your before_filter only work on one of your actions

```
before_filter :set_toppings, :only => [ :show_pizza_topping ]
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Here's some more information on [filters in ActionController](http://www.railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.4/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: Yes it does, thank you. However, shortly after posting this I found another answer (I updated the question to reflect this). When is the best time to use before_filter and/or initialize?

Comment: I would say that you should use a before_filter if it's any sort of set up work that has to work on multiple actions.

Comment: As an example of the comment I just left, when verifying that someone is logged in, you might typically have a method in `ApplicationController` and apply a `before_filter` to any action that requires the user be logged in. It wouldn't make sense having that code in every action that requires someone be logged in.

Comment: Understood - this would make it easier to split up into multiple filter methods if necessary, and/or allocate to specific action(s) if necessary. Thank you - that's a bit of a Ruby gotcha when you come from C-like languages.

Comment: For better organization and readability it's better to use before_filter.

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't instance variables, are they?

```
class A
  @x = 5
  def f
    puts @x
  end
end

A.new.f
=> nil
```

You're defining it at the class-level, not the instance-level.  As "theIV" points out, you need to assign them inside an instance method.

Comment: I was under the mistaken impression you could do it in that way like in languages such as c# or Java:

class ExampleController {
    private string var1 = "cheese";
    // ...
}

Comment: In Java, there, you're declaring an instance variable; in Ruby, you variables are not declared, so there's no real equivalent.  Anything inside the Ruby "class".."end" is basically evaluated, so it might help to think of that as equivalent to a Java static initializer.